# JavaCC Android port User Interface (Activity) class

Tags: java, android, compiler

I have been working on a port of JavaCC for Android. It is mainly an interface. I needed only to modify the original source to redirect output to a TextView. The point of this project is to rekindle my coding skills after years of dormancy, to actually finish a coding project, and to make a useful port of JavaCC that I can use to play around with AIDE. This project was actually made in part with AIDE. I am excited to read your opinion on my code regarding what I consider to be the most difficult portion of the code. I was able to modularize many portions of this UI package, but this class persisted to be difficult. Please feel free to ask any applicable questions.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Context context;
    private String[] menuOptions = new String[] { "view license",
            "view parameters", "run program", "view output" };
    private Runnable[] menuOptionThreads = new Runnable[] { new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                println(getLicenseString().toString(), handler);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                println("Error reading license file.", handler);
            }
            scrolly.removeAllViews();
            scrolly.addView(text);
        }
    }, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrolly.removeAllViews();
            scrolly.addView(linear);
        }

    }, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            text.setText("");
            scrolly.removeAllViews();
            scrolly.addView(text);
            new Run(handler, options, fPath, fOutPath);
        }

    }, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            scrolly.removeAllViews();
            scrolly.addView(text);
        }

    } };
    private TextView text;
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            final String messageString = message.getData().getString("print");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (text == null)
                        return;
                    text.setText(text.getText() + messageString + "\n");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    private static Option options[];
    private static String fPath;
    private static String fOutPath;
    private ScrollView scrolly;
    private LinearLayout linear;
    private EditText path;
    private EditText outPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        Streams.error = new PrintStream(new Streams.ErrorStream(handler));
        Streams.standard = new PrintStream(new Streams.StandardStream(handler));
        LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrolly = new ScrollView(this);
        linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        try {
            fPath = getIntent().getDataString();
            fPath = fPath.substring(fPath.indexOf("//") + 2);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            fPath = "/";
        }
        text = new TextView(this);
        options = Option.generateDefaultOptionsObjectsArray();

        Button menuButton = new Button(this);
        menuButton.setText("menu");
        new AppMenu(context, menuOptions, menuButton, MainActivity.this,
                menuOptionThreads);
        Button fileSelectButton = new Button(this);
        fileSelectButton.setText("file");
        new FileSelect(context, new File("/").list(), fileSelectButton,
                MainActivity.this, "/", false);
        path = new EditText(this);
        path.setText(fPath);
        path.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3,
                    int p4) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                fPath = arg0.toString();
                int dot = fPath.lastIndexOf(".");
                    if (dot > 0) outPath.setText(fPath.substring(0, dot));
            }
        });
        outPath = new EditText(this);
        outPath.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                fOutPath = arg0.toString();
            }

        });
        LinearLayout outPathOuterView = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView outPathLabel = new TextView(this);
        outPathLabel.setText(Option.OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_OPTION);
        outPathOuterView.addView(outPathLabel);
        outPathOuterView.addView(outPath);
        linear.addView(outPathOuterView);
        for (Option option : options)
            linear.addView(generateViewForOption(option));
        LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        topLayout.addView(menuButton);
        topLayout.addView(fileSelectButton);
        topLayout.addView(path);
        rootView.addView(topLayout);
        scrolly.addView(linear);
        rootView.addView(scrolly);
        setContentView(rootView);
    }

    private CharSequence getLicenseString() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.license);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while (is.available() > 0)
            result.append((char) is.read());
        return result.toString();
    }

    private LinearLayout generateViewForOption(final Option option) {
        LinearLayout result = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        name.setText(option.getOptionName() + " = ");
        result.addView(name);
        if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.INTEGER)) {
            EditText value = new EditText(this);
            value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            value.setText(String.valueOf(option.getInt()));
            option.setValueView(value);
            result.addView(value);
        } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.BOOLEAN)) {
            CheckBox value = new CheckBox(this);
            value.setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(option.getBool()));
            option.setValueView(value);
            result.addView(value);
        } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.STRING_OPTIONLISTABLE)) {
            Button value = new Button(this);
            value.setText(option.getCurrentValueAsString());
            new ParameterPopup(context, option.getPossibleOptions(), value);
            option.setValueView(value);
            result.addView(value);
        } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.STRING)) {
            EditText value = new EditText(this);
            value.setText(option.getCurrentValueAsString());
            option.setValueView(value);
            result.addView(value);
        } else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        result.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return result;
    }

    public static void println(String string, Handler handler) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("print", string);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void setfpath(final String pathString) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                path.setText(pathString);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice way to break down your previous question into smaller pieces!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private String[] menuOptions = new String[] { "view license",
        "view parameters", "run program", "view output" };
private Runnable[] menuOptionThreads = new Runnable[] { new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            println(getLicenseString().toString(), handler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            println("Error reading license file.", handler);
        }
        scrolly.removeAllViews();
        scrolly.addView(text);
    }
}, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrolly.removeAllViews();
        scrolly.addView(linear);
    }

}, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        text.setText("");
        scrolly.removeAllViews();
        scrolly.addView(text);
        new Run(handler, options, fPath, fOutPath);
    }

}, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        scrolly.removeAllViews();
        scrolly.addView(text);
    }

} };
```

So, there's an abstract "menu option" of sorts that has a `String` and `Runnable`.

Turn it into a class.

---

You could use some blank lines in your code. `onCreate` reads as a wall of text, and without semantic breaks ("paragraphs"), it's hard to see at a glance what's going on.

Additionally, you'll find that blank lines show how a function would be split up into other functions.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    Streams.error = new PrintStream(new Streams.ErrorStream(handler));
    Streams.standard = new PrintStream(new Streams.StandardStream(handler));
    LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrolly = new ScrollView(this);
    linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    try {
        fPath = getIntent().getDataString();
        fPath = fPath.substring(fPath.indexOf("//") + 2);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        fPath = "/";
    }
    text = new TextView(this);
    options = Option.generateDefaultOptionsObjectsArray();

    Button menuButton = new Button(this);
    menuButton.setText("menu");
    new AppMenu(context, menuOptions, menuButton, MainActivity.this,
            menuOptionThreads);
    Button fileSelectButton = new Button(this);
    fileSelectButton.setText("file");
    new FileSelect(context, new File("/").list(), fileSelectButton,
            MainActivity.this, "/", false);
    path = new EditText(this);
    path.setText(fPath);
    path.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3,
                int p4) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence p1, int p2, int p3, int p4) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            fPath = arg0.toString();
            int dot = fPath.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (dot > 0) outPath.setText(fPath.substring(0, dot));
        }
    });
    outPath = new EditText(this);
    outPath.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            fOutPath = arg0.toString();
        }

    });
    LinearLayout outPathOuterView = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView outPathLabel = new TextView(this);
    outPathLabel.setText(Option.OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_OPTION);
    outPathOuterView.addView(outPathLabel);
    outPathOuterView.addView(outPath);
    linear.addView(outPathOuterView);
    for (Option option : options)
        linear.addView(generateViewForOption(option));
    LinearLayout topLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    topLayout.addView(menuButton);
    topLayout.addView(fileSelectButton);
    topLayout.addView(path);
    rootView.addView(topLayout);
    scrolly.addView(linear);
    rootView.addView(scrolly);
    setContentView(rootView);
}
```

I'd start by sorting relevant lines.

`fPath` is defined as some value in a try catch, but then not used until 10 statements later. By sorting the statements you can say "this region handles fPath, that region handles..." I would give examples, but the code is a bit confusing right now.

Lastly, once you have blank lines, I'd suggest migrating whole paragraphs to separate functions. The function as a whole is too long. A good start would be migrating `outPath` and `path` out of the `onCreate` function, as the listeners take a lot of vertical space.

---

```
    if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.INTEGER)) {
        EditText value = new EditText(this);
        value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        value.setText(String.valueOf(option.getInt()));
        option.setValueView(value);
        result.addView(value);
    } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.BOOLEAN)) {
        CheckBox value = new CheckBox(this);
        value.setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(option.getBool()));
        option.setValueView(value);
        result.addView(value);
    } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.STRING_OPTIONLISTABLE)) {
        Button value = new Button(this);
        value.setText(option.getCurrentValueAsString());
        new ParameterPopup(context, option.getPossibleOptions(), value);
        option.setValueView(value);
        result.addView(value);
    } else if (option.getType().equals(Option.Type.STRING)) {
        EditText value = new EditText(this);
        value.setText(option.getCurrentValueAsString());
        option.setValueView(value);
        result.addView(value)
```

First, migrate the bodies of these conditionals to separate functions. `createEditText`, `createCheckbox`, etc.

This helps anyone that wishes to understand the function - if the option type is a boolean it will create a checkbox, if the option type is a ... then they will create a...

The details of creating something aren't relevant in a function that decides what has to be created.